# Case in namespace reference doesn't match the case in declaration (PHP Inspection EA Extended)

Tags: php, namespaces, phpstorm

> NOTE: PHP Inspector EA Extended version 4.0.6.3

I have a new project with some existing imported classes, and PHP Inspection (EA Extended) plugin for PHPStorm is coming up with:

> Case in namespace reference doesn't match the case in declaration

when setting a namespace on a PHP page. Yet the case is **identical** to the filepath, class references and all usage cases that I can find.

I can't find any useful reference when searching for this term.

## PHP Class:

```
<?php
    namespace myVendorName\ProjectName;
    
    Class AbstractClass {
    
    }
```

## Filepath:

> /classes/vendor/myVendorName/ProjectName/AbstractClass.php
> /classes/vendor/autoloader.php
> (etc)

## Endpoint PHP File:

```
<?php

use myVendorName\ProjectName\AbstractClass;
$dropValue  = new AbstractClass();
```

## What does it claim is correct?

PHP Inspection EA Extended wants to change my namespace call in my class files to `namespace myvendorname\ProjectName`.  It wants to lower the case of the primary vendor name to all lower case.

Yet the [Autoloading standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) states:

> 2. 5. Alphabetic characters in the fully qualified class name MAY be any combination of lower case and upper case.

## Inconsistency?

The namespace declaration of `namespace myVendorName;` (with no project subname) in the class file raises no flags with the Inspector. Yet with the project name it suddenly wants to change the case of the vendor name prefix. The projectname is required for the autoloader pathing so.... ?

---

I have looked over the whole project and I can't find anywhere where anything references this namespace, I believe I have checked and confirmed all the settings and values both in PHPStorm as well as on the live server.

- Am I being really stupid and missing something?
- Is this an issue with the plugin?

**What is the "declaration" that the Inspector is referencing as the source for its complaint?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found it.**

The issue was that PHPStorm has an "include Path" listing of, er, include paths, and within this listing was a path to a server folder for a few shared files.

Within this server side file structure was one root leveled class that had a namespace declared on it which was a lowercase duplication of the vendor namespace.

PHP Inspection (EA Extended) was detecting this and concluding somehow that the files in the server shared folder was taking precendent over the project-specific `/vendors/` folder.

The class file that was in the shared folder is not used by this project and is not referenced by this project, the reference is entirely within PHPStorm's settings only.

Removing this reference (acutally, removing the erroneous namespace call to `myvendorname`) clears up all these issues.